# Meaning of a mathematical symbol

Tags: notation

I'm reading the following [Introduction to p-adic numbers](http://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/REU2020/REUPapers/Pomerantz.pdf) by Alexa Pomeranz

Towards the end of page 2, there's a symbol unknown to me. Selecting and copying it, copies a hyphen `-` symbol instead, so I cannot copy the actual symbol to search for it.

I highlighted the symbol in yellow.

What does this symbol mean?

[image]

Comment: $p$ does not divide $x'$

Comment: Compare with Wikipedia [p-adic valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_valuation).

Comment: [does not divide](https://graphemica.com/%E2%88%A4#:~:text=%E2%88%A4%20%7C%20does%20not%20divide%20(U%2B2224)%20%40%20Graphemica)